# Call and pass arguments to other script and store echo

Tags: bash

I'm calling another script and passing the required arguments like this:

***main.sh***

```sh
bash menu.sh "${#map_list[@]}" "${map_list[@]}""${#index_list[@]}" "${index_list[@]}" $title
```

***menu.sh***

```sh
options=( "${@:2:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"
results=( "${@:2:$1}" ); shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"

declare -p options results

title=$1
### more code beneath to pop a multi option menu ... ###
```

and this pops the menu properly:

[image: working menu]

however, i need to store the options that were picked and echo a string

***menu.sh***

```sh
echo $chosen
```

and attempted liked this:

***main.sh***

```sh
chosen=$(bash menu.sh "${#map_list[@]}" "${map_list[@]}" "${#index_list[@]}" "${index_list[@]}" $title)
```

but the menu doesn't show any options just shows the instruction string, seeming that arguments aren't properly passed somehow

[image: not working menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menu.sh` is printing the "Check an option" prompt to stderr but the options are being printed to stdout. `$(...)` captures stdout so the options aren't visible.

Edit `menu.sh` and have it print the options to stderr with `>&2`.

Comment: That was it chief, https://github.com/OriDevTeam/Instant-Manager/commit/713a1555a52ed5cd486e38e258cb8a3a86007961#diff-77a8c3c7ae72eefd3c38ca0488caab98 to https://github.com/OriDevTeam/Instant-Manager/commit/229e88da9c781224afe9c584d45086556d4f44c6#diff-77a8c3c7ae72eefd3c38ca0488caab98 did the job, thank you for the explanation